# Trying to loop through elements and set styles at same time

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have an angular material table

(HTML)

```
<table mat-table
                [dataSource]="dataSource" multiTemplateDataRows
                class="mat-elevation-z8">
          <ng-container *ngIf="{{column}}" matColumnDef="{{column}}" *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column}} </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[column]}} </td>
          </ng-container>
```

I want to change the styling on the element if it equals 'Missing' (e.g. {{element[column}} == Missing then change styling).

(style) (HTML)

```
<mat-chip *ngIf="element.status=='Missing'" style="background-color: #ec9d9d; color: red">Missing</mat-chip>
```

How can I do this in the HTML? I only want to do this if the displayedColumn 'status' is equal to 'Missing'.

(Typescript)

```
  displayedColumns: string[] = [
    'id',
    'tradingPartnerTradingPartner',
    'fileFormatFileFormat',
    'status',
  ];
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use the [ng-class directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

in your example, using it should be something like this:
(Assuming the mat-chip would get placed into this cell I modified below)

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" multiTemplateDataRows
                 class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container *ngIf="{{column}}" matColumnDef="{{column}}" *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column}} </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"
               [ngClass]="{missing: element.status=='Missing' }"> {{element[column]}} </td>
  </ng-container>
...
```

and don't forget to create the css for the `.missing` class we are referencing in the `ngClass` directive:

```
.missing {
  background-color: #ec9d9d;
  color: red
}
```

Comment: I was able to add the class attribute for the row. However, I just want the column to be red (currently it is highlighting the entire row red). How can I just highlight the 'status' column to be red instead of the entire table row?

Comment: `[ngClass]="{missing: (column =='status' && element[column]=='Missing')}"`  replace this condition in your ngClass

Comment: You forgot a single quotes in missing: `[ngClass]="{'missing': element.status=='Missing' }"`. NOTE you can also use `[class.missing]="element.status=='Missing'"` or `[ngClass]="element.status=='Missing'?'missing':null`

Comment: n.. the single quote is actually optional